# Graph: TreeSet is not adding all the edges

Tags: java, graph, set, treeset

I am working on an **undirected graph** problem. I have a `Node` class which contains `nodeName` and `List<Edge>`. Then I have `Edge` class which holds `Node start`, `Node end` and `weight`. And finally I have a `Graph` class which has one instance variable `Map<String, Node>`.

I want to add all distinct edges to a set and order them in an increasing order based on their edge weight. Hence I chose `TreeSet` to store all the edges in an unique sorted fashion. But when I call the `addAllEdges()` it doesn't add all the edges. The graph has 9 vertices and 14 edges. However the treeSet saves only 10 of those.

[image]

Code Structure:

**Graph:**

```
class Graph {
    private Map<String, Node> verticesMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void addEdge(String src, String dest, int weight) {
        Node srcNode = verticesMap.get(src) == null ? new Node(src) : verticesMap.get(src);
        Node destNode = verticesMap.get(dest) == null ? new Node(dest) : verticesMap.get(dest);
        Edge edge = new Edge(srcNode, destNode, weight);
        srcNode.getEdgeList().add(edge);
        verticesMap.put(src, srcNode);
        verticesMap.put(dest, destNode);
    }

    public Set<Edge> addAllEdges() {
        Set<Edge> allEdgesSet = new TreeSet<>(getComparatorBasedOnEdgeWeight());
        for (Node node : verticesMap.values()) {
            for (Edge edge : node.getEdgeList()) {
            // sysout for debugging purpose only
                if(allEdgesSet.add(edge)) {
                    System.out.println("Added edge: " + edge);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Did not add edge: " + edge);
                }
            }
        }
        return allEdgesSet;
    }

    private Comparator<Edge> getComparatorBasedOnEdgeWeight() {
        return (e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.getWeight(), e2.getWeight());
    }
}
```

**Node:**

```
class Node {
    private String name;
    private List<Edge> edgeList;

    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        edgeList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Node other = (Node) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Edge:**

```
class Edge {
    private Node src;
    private Node dest;
    private int weight;

    public Edge(Node src, Node dest, int weight) {
        this.src = src;
        this.dest = dest;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((dest == null) ? 0 : dest.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((src == null) ? 0 : src.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Edge other = (Edge) obj;
        if (dest == null) {
            if (other.dest != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dest.equals(other.dest))
            return false;
        if (src == null) {
            if (other.src != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!src.equals(other.src))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return src + "-->" + dest + "[" + weight + "]";
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
 public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Graph graph = new Graph();
            graph.addEdge("A", "B", 4);
            graph.addEdge("B", "A", 4);
            graph.addEdge("A", "I", 8);
            graph.addEdge("I", "A", 8);
            graph.addEdge("B", "C", 8);
            graph.addEdge("C", "B", 8);
            graph.addEdge("B", "I", 11);
            graph.addEdge("I", "B", 11);
            graph.addEdge("C", "H", 2);
            graph.addEdge("H", "C", 2);
            graph.addEdge("C", "D", 7);
            graph.addEdge("D", "C", 7);
            graph.addEdge("C", "F", 4);
            graph.addEdge("F", "C", 4);
            graph.addEdge("H", "I", 7);
            graph.addEdge("I", "H", 7);
            graph.addEdge("H", "G", 6);
            graph.addEdge("G", "H", 6);
            graph.addEdge("I", "G", 1);
            graph.addEdge("G", "I", 1);
            graph.addEdge("G", "F", 2);
            graph.addEdge("F", "G", 2);
            graph.addEdge("F", "D", 14);
            graph.addEdge("D", "F", 14);
            graph.addEdge("F", "E", 10);
            graph.addEdge("E", "F", 10);
            graph.addEdge("E", "D", 9);
            graph.addEdge("D", "E", 9);
            graph.addAllEdges();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Added edge: A-->B[4]
Added edge: A-->I[9]
Did not add edge: B-->A[4]
Added edge: B-->C[8]
Added edge: B-->I[11]
Did not add edge: C-->B[8]
Added edge: C-->H[2]
Added edge: C-->D[7]
Did not add edge: C-->F[4]
Did not add edge: D-->C[7]
Added edge: D-->F[14]
Did not add edge: D-->E[9]
Added edge: E-->F[10]
Did not add edge: E-->D[9]
Did not add edge: F-->C[4]
Did not add edge: F-->G[2]
Did not add edge: F-->D[14]
Did not add edge: F-->E[10]
Added edge: G-->H[6]
Added edge: G-->I[1]
Did not add edge: G-->F[2]
Did not add edge: H-->C[2]
Did not add edge: H-->I[7]
Did not add edge: H-->G[6]
Did not add edge: I-->A[9]
Did not add edge: I-->B[11]
Did not add edge: I-->H[7]
Did not add edge: I-->G[1]

Edges in the TreeSet:
[G-->I[1], C-->H[2], A-->B[4], G-->H[6], C-->D[7], B-->C[8], A-->I[9], E-->F[10], B-->I[11], D-->F[14]]
```

The output above shows that it is iterating through 28 edges (14 vertices * 2). I am not able to figure out why treeSet is returning false for those edges which aren't even present in the set yet.

Comment: Some of the edges have the same weight. They will only appear once in the resulting set. (Details can be read in other answers). Instead of a `TreeSet`, you should use a `List` (e.g. `ArrayList`), and then sort it with `Collections.sort(list, yourWeightComparator);`.

Comment: @Marco13: Thanks a lot for your comment. I was reading Andreas answer and you are right about. I will try to solve this problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeSet` uses the `Comparator` for the ordering, but also for the uniqueness of objects. It does not use `equals()` or `hashCode()`.

Your `Comparator` needs to compare nodes too, e.g. using node name.

Also, if your graph was truly [***undirected***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Undirected_graph), you should not need to do `graph.addEdge("A", "B", 4)` *and* `graph.addEdge("B", "A", 4)`, since they represent the same undirected edge. An undirected edge has no "source" or "destination".

I would suggest that you change `Edge`, renaming `src` and `dest` to `node1` and `node2`, and ensure that name of `node1` is less than name of `node2`.

That way, your `Comparator` can then simply compare `weight`, `node1.name`, and `node2.name`:

```
private Comparator<Edge> getComparatorBasedOnEdgeWeight() {
    return (e1, e2) -> {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(e1.getWeight(), e2.getWeight());
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = e1.getNode1().getName().compareTo(e2.getNode1().getName());
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = e1.getNode2().getName().compareTo(e2.getNode2().getName());
        return cmp;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick solution. Let me work on it now. Thanks